# Is it possible to get the default options for a Tkinter widget without instantiating its class?

Tags: python, configuration, tkinter, instantiation

This prints the default option configuration for the `Text` widget. Would it be possible to get this information without instantiating the `Text` widget class?

```
import Tkinter as tk
import pprint

root = tk.Tk()

text = tk.Text(root)
text.pack()

pprint.pprint(text.configure())

root.destroy()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible. It's quite acceptable to instantiate the class then destroy the widget once you have the information you need.